# XEvent Handling in animation

Tags: animation, gcc, event-handling, keypress, xlib

I'm having some understanding problem of event-handling with Xlib functions.

My question would be - how do i press a key during an animation, without disturbing the animation.

My setup so far, is that i have some animation in a while loop and want to achieve a KeyPress event which modifies a parameter.

It looks something like this

> > while(1){
> >     XNextEvent(dis, &report);
> >           switch  (report.type) {
> >               case KeyPress:
> >                 if (XLookupKeysym(&report.xkey, 0) == XK_space){
> >                             //...modify parameter a..//
> > }}
> >     //...Some animation where parameter a is used to modify animation...//
> > }

Now, the problem is that i have to press the key consistently to get the animation on my screen, otherwise nothing appears. I've tried some multiple code-modifications, with KeyRelease etc. but i don't have clou, really.

Trivially said - i need to hook a key during animation without the XNextEvent process, waiting for any event. But without the XNextEvent statement in my code, conditional statements for KeyPress event checking aren't working.

I guess formally this would mean:

> > while(1){
> >           if(report.type==KeyPress) {
> >                 if (XLookupKeysym(&report.xkey, 0) == XK_space){
> >                             //...modify parameter a..//
> > }}
> >     //...Some animation where parameter a is used to modify animation...//
> > }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XPending()` to check for XEvents before getting them with `XNextEvent()`.

`XPending()` returns then number of events in the event queue so modify your loop:

```
   while(1){
     if (XPending(dis) > 0) {
       XNextEvent(dis, &report);
       switch (report.type) {
         case KeyPress:
           if (XLookupKeysym(&report.xkey, 0) == XK_space){
              //...modify parameter a..//
           }
        }
     }
     //...Some animation where parameter a is used to modify animation...//
   }
```

Comment: exactly what i had in mind, one event per key-press. Thank you!